nestjs pdf-creator-node error Unknown system error -8
I am creating a service with nestjs, I use pdf-creator-node when I run locally it generates the perfect pdf but when I docker I get an error {
"answer": {
"error": -8,
"code": "Unknown system error -8",
"syscall": "generate"
},
"status": 500,
"message": "generate unknown system error -8",
"name": "HttpException"
} I attach the problem code
When I run locally it generates the pdf, but when I docker I get an error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
